Correctly stack road segments while having nice endings
I'm trying to correctly lay out a road system in QGIS. My public data source can be found here.
I've clipped the data source to a boundary. And then set the road endings to have a rounded end, which gave me roads that looked like this:

Obviously, all the roads blended like isn't ideal. I found this thread which showed how to correctly stack the roads, and that got me a lot closer:

This works a lot better on the stacks, but the edge of my clippings looks bad. I tried duplicating the layer and put the old system below the new one, but that doesn't quite work because of how I needed to use a Square cap style on the white segments:

If I put my cap types as round with my edges as flat, I get very close, but there are still some lines that aren't quite right at the connection points:

zoomed out they're still slightly visible 
Am I missing any options to get this to look as clean as I'd like?
Overall, I'd like:

Roads stacked correctly
Road edges (black lines) fully connected
Road ends to be rounded


Are nice endings different from happy endings?

You might try a different symbology join style?

@John, the only one that's left is straight and that also has weird artifacts that are worse.

use symbol levels? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/344013/276

@Mapperz, I already mentioned I'm using that in my post.
